# Can I host my own Mysql Database?

Tags: mysql

Our teacher ask us if we can make our database online
so we buy a hosting plan but it's to slow.
I don't want to buy or upgrade my hosting plan.

So I'm thinking if I can host my own Mysql Server.
 
My Current PC Specs is i7 and 16GB RAM with 50MBPS internet connection.

Comment: Short answer: you can host a local version of MySQL. Long answer: this is offtopic for Stackoverflow, I think googling or visiting [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) will help you out.

Comment: Depends on how big your database is, for small DB's you can make use of [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: You can't connect to sqlfiddle with a sql client @UdayrajDeshmukh

Comment: "so we buy a hosting plan but it's to slow." how is it slow?

Comment: I bet any host plan you can buy has enough performance for any kind of student project. *Slow* is what your code is unless you deal with several hundred millions of rows.

Comment: sorry for asking, I keep googling for 3 hours. so I tried to ask here.

Comment: It's just a small database wtih 7 tables.

Comment: I created a simple Sales and Invetory System. when the system tried to put values on a data grid it finished with 5-10 sec. plus the hosting that I buy is table case sensitive just like select table LOGIN; it error cause in my PHPadmin tables is small letters.

Comment: If you are having difficulties at this level, you can expect to fail getting your database up and running before your project is due. Try to use as much pre-configured as possible, change what you need (case sensitive) and concentrate on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you technically could.

You could easily set up [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

The more complicated part would be accessing that from an external network.

You would have to set up your router with a static IP or with a dynamic dns and then forward ports.

Comment: thank you sir for the answer, do I need to subnetting?

Comment: No you wont. There are many tutorials online of how to set this up. I have done it a few times using a raspberry pi which is good for learning how to create your own web server.

Comment: Thank you sir, now I will do my part.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - Yes.

You will have to though take care of below things when you go about managing your own database.

1. Have a static ip
2. Database backup strategy
3. Backup restoration strategy
4. Horizontal scaling / vertical scaling strategy
5. Sharding and replication (if needed)
6. Managing security

Comment: Ok sir I will try.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your computer configuration is ok. But Dear if don't buy or upgrade your hosting plan you have to purchase a real ip address which is more costly for you. But you can talk with your ISP for providing a real ip against your current connection. because your current internet connection is good enough for you.

Comment: So that's it, I don't have choice but to upgrade my hosting since I'm not using Lease line . Thanks for this.